# How to put parameters in python while requesting api

Tags: python

I'm trying to put a parameter in python
The code I'm using:

```
import requests

api = ("https://apiv2.nethergames.org/v1/guilds/Oasis%20II")
params = {'expand':True , 'withStats':True }

json_data = requests.get(api, params=params)
print(json_data.text)
```

The error i get:

```
{"code":0,"message":"Invalid Form Body","errors":[{"keyword":"type","dataPath":".expand","schemaPath":"GuildQuery#/properties/expand/type","params":{"type":"boolean"},"message":"should be boolean"}]}

[Program finished]
```

It says it should be a boolean but it already is a boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is expecting `true` instead of `True`.

Updating your code like the following resolves the issue.

```py
import requests

api = ("https://apiv2.nethergames.org/v1/guilds/Oasis%20II")
params = {'expand': "true", 'withStats': "true"}

json_data = requests.get(api, params=params)
print(json_data.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this code, please add the following lines

```
import json
params = json.dumps({'expand':True , 'withStats':True })
```

So you code becomes:

```
import requests
import json


api = ("https://apiv2.nethergames.org/v1/guilds/Oasis%20II")
params = json.dumps({'expand':True , 'withStats':True })

json_data = requests.get(api, params=params)
print(json_data.text)
```

I tested this before posting here, it works!